# How to use constexpr in this case?

Tags: c++11

I try to write function with constexpr

```
constexpr QString c(const QString &columnName);
```

but it output issue:

> enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function 'QString
>   DatabaseHandler::c(const QString&) const' is not a literal type
>        constexpr QString c(const QString &columnName);

I very bad know C++ 11 yet so cannot undestand this bug. What does it mean?

P.S. If I add `static` then it also output issue **Invalid return type 'QString'**.

Answer (score 7):

`constexpr` functions require that their input arguments and their return type are [literal types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType), and therefore must have at least one `constexpr` constructor. `Qstring` (i.e, the return type) does not, thus you get a compiler error.

Comment: I didn't know... Thanks! I read now that Qt 4.8 supports C++ 11, so I think that it must have this constructor. Or I don't understand something?

Comment: A reference type is a literal type. In the OP's case, it's the return type that is not of a literal type, isn't it?

Comment: I found now `QStringLiteral` define but I cannot understand how to use it

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yeah, I corrected thanx, you rock ;)